# Classification between name and non name

Tags: java, classification, semantics

I am looking for a way to classify the input string as a name or non-name. e.g. : I have 2 inputs : Mary and lawyer. Then the out put should be :
Mary : name
lawyer : non-name

Does somebody know any API or something which can do this for me. I know a website [behind the names](http://www.behindthename.com/name/) which does this. But I don't know how to call and use it from my java code.

Update : I found that there is an [API](http://www.behindthename.com/api/) for the above mentioned site. This helps in classification.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can have a standard like this. It would be a design mistake. This will be error prone. If a user is going to input their names and professions, then why not asking them first for the name and then profession rather than trying to figure out which input is name and which one is profession. You also need to consider that some names can consist of multiple names like a first name can be "Mary Ann", "Rose Ann", etc.

But if you have to, have a list of possible professions (not names) which should be better to distinguish.

Comment: I found an API for the above mentioned site, please check the latest edit.

Comment: @tejas You have to register to use their API. Why don't you? But this is not recommended. I don't like this approach to figure out if a string is name. Doesn't make sense. Something is wrong with the application design.

Comment: yes I did and I have started using the API as well. Why do you think the approach is wrong.
See the bigger picture is : I have several sentences, each of which contain 2 candidates in them. And my aim is to determine which of the sentence contains a person name, so that I can treat them specially.

Comment: Parse this sentence - "George Washington went to Washington yesterday". Read on Natural Language Processing. :)

Comment: yes you are right. But my sentences aren't going to be that complicated as to use natural language processing.

Comment: @tejas In that case use a list/file containing all the possible professions. Trust me - this way it'll be less pain. If you really want to read the name database, read on this, might help - http://alvinalexander.com/java/edu/pj/pj010011

Comment: @tejas - That's great. :)